# Bar Graph for two field with same values in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

My data in excel sheet look like below,

```
Exam Required Held
Maths A3 A2
Science A2 A3
English A1 A1
Social A3 A2
Test1 A1 A1  
Test2 A1 NA
```

I want to create a graph in tableau in this way,
[image]

I want A1,A2 and A3 as values only so that I can take count of Required and held in same bar.

Please suggest any approach to achieve this.

Comment: Either you can exclude NA or keep only A1,A2,A3 by right click on values

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would like to have something like this:

[image]

I just duplicated rows in your sample to make it easier to look at.
`held count` is a `count([Held])`. same for the Required.